# Deploying with Truffle

Tags: web3js, truffle

I deployed a contract through remix and then I run the following code

```
MyContract.deployed()
    .then(instance => {
    c = instance;
    return c.getCreator();
})
    .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(`${error}`);
})
```

It spits an error saying 
`Error: HelloWorld has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)`

HelloWorld is just a JSON file that contains my ABI/Binary/etc generated from truffle

Comment: Is the contract deployed to a local network i.e  testrpc or  to a different netwok ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- the truffle web3 provider is connected to the same network which you deployed to.
- the ABI file contains the deployed contract address.

You can also specify the contract address to use:

```
MyContract.at(contractAddress)
.then(instance => {
  // ...
})
```

If deploying make sure that:

- You have a wallet connected. You can use [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider).

  `var provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://mainnet.infura.io:443')`
- You are including `from` in the options. You can also set it using `defaults()`. See [truffle-contract documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider).

Comment: What if I don't use `MyContract.at(contractAddress)` but instead `MyContract.new()` ? It spits an Error: Invalid address

Comment: @JorahFriendzone that error is because it's not detecting a connected wallet. If you have one connected, then also include the `{from: account}` option